# Как заменить NaN в датасете?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, анализ-данных, обработка-данных

В датасете есть столбец с номинативными переменными, в ячейках которого присутствуют пустые значения NaN.

Можно ли как-то заменить или заполнить эти значения, например, не самым часто встречающимся значением, а с частотой, с которой встречаются имеющиеся данные?

Например, столбец `Пол`:
в нём 2/3 `м` и 1/3 `ж`. и заполнить пустые значения на 2/3 `м` и на 1/3 `ж`.

Comment: Уточните, что именно вызывает проблему - как найти пустые значения. или как сделать вероятностное присвоение?

Comment: @Sergey вероятностное присвоение

Comment: "вероятностное присвоение" - На самом деле никакого смысла в **вероятностном** присваивании нет. Вам просто нужно, что 2 из трёх были мужчины, а 1 - женщины. Достаточно завести функцию, которая просто по порядку возвращает элементы списка {M, M, F) - и статистика не нарушится.

Comment: если один столбец, то удобнее. но у меня их несколько и через вероятностное присваивание, мне кажется, удобнее @Sergey

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Алгоритм действий:

1. Создайте переменную маску - “mask”, состоящую из булевых значений и показывающую строки в которых столбец «пол» имеет значение NaN
2. Посчитайте число True в mask и сохраните полученное значение в переменную “n”.
3. Выбрав по маске “mask” нужные строки и столбец «пол», присвойте “n” случайных значений, воспользовавшись функцией [np.random.choice и параметром “p”](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.choice.html) - для задания того с какой вероятностью выбирать значения.

---

```
mask = df["sex"].isna()
# считаем статистику распределения значений
p = df["sex"].value_counts() / len(df["sex"].dropna())
# заполняем пропуски с вероятностью `p`
df.loc[mask, "sex"] = \
    np.random.choice(p.index.to_list(), 
                     size=mask.sum(), 
                     p=p.to_list())
```

---

PS если решение не совсем понятно - советую выполнять его по шагам и смотреть, что получилось на каждом шаге...